# Fastest assembly code for finding the square root. Explanation needed

Tags: c, assembly, root, inline-assembly, sqrt

I'm currently making a program in C that needs to find billions of square roots. I looked up which known code finds the square root faster and came across this code which is seemingly the fastest. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/69941/Best-Square-Root-Method-Algorithm-Function-Precisi

```
double inline __declspec (naked) __fastcall sqrt(double n)
{
    _asm fld qword ptr[esp + 4]
    _asm fsqrt
    _asm ret 8
}
```

I don't know much about assembly language so can someone please explain what this code does algorithmically and what those keywords mean?

Comment: It is an algorithm implemented by the "fsqrt" opcode into the cpu/fpu microcode.

Comment: Definitively *not* the fastest code around (or even close). There are only three instructions, one being a return. There is basically nothing to say.

Comment: Be very, very wary of using inline assembly where there are library functions available. The compiler does zero checking that the assembly even makes sense. You defeat all the benefits the compiler provides by saying "I know what I'm doing and I can do it better than you can." Today's compilers are very good at optimizing code, and there is little chance that some code you find on the web is going to do a better job than what your compiler will do. (and the downside to getting the assembly wrong will always outweigh any marginal increase in performance)

Comment: @MargaretBloom Have you tried using it? It is actually very accurate and super fast. I've compared it with the standard sqrt function and also created a binary search method but this one is way faster.

Comment: @JasonJames, not need to. The FPU is an old ISA. Consider moving to AVX/SSE. Even keeping the same algorithm, an instruction like `VSQRTPD` has slightly worst tput than `fsqrt` (on skl) but can operate on 2 or 4 inputs at a time. It still wastes a lot of resources if there isn't anything else to use them. Depending on your needs, properly implementing an approximation may or may not improve your code tput.

Comment: @MargaretBloom even a very slight change in approximation wont make my code work. I'm trying to get the square roots of numbers bigger than ten trillion. Would you still recommend changing the solution?

Comment: The stdlib sqrt should be at least of the same speed. Can you show the C code, how you tested the library C, and what compile time options do you use? Plus disassembly?  ... about big numbers like ten trillion... do you understand, that the `double` itself does store only limited amount of digits, so ten trillion = 10^12 -> 12 digits for the integer part and `double` can store only about 15-17 digits almost accurately. Makes me wonder whether your `double` results are really that accurate, and what kind of problem you have with slightly off approximation.

Comment: And even if the old x87 `fsqrt` would be fastest for your case, and the difference would be considerable (to replace lib `sqrt` with this), then you are probably in situation where the whole loop may benefit from proper rewrite into assembly, because the function you posted will hardly play well with other calculations, as it loads the value from memory into FP stack, while if it would be integral with the other calculations in loop, it would have maybe the value already on FP stack, saving one memory write+read. But you can surely gain more from vectorization and SSE usage.

Comment: So could you provide a faster code with almost as good accuracy?

Comment: @JasonJames no, you would have to provide whole main loop, like for example https://godbolt.org/g/hEJ6mh  (notice the main code-path after `.L5` label calculating 8 elements at the same time with AVX512 instructions) ... if you have CPU with AVX512, this will easily beat any x87 variant machine code to death, probably even inaccurate approximations. Next possible performance step is GPU... Optimizing single function or operation is pointless with modern C++ (and C, but I prefer C++) compilers, you need real code to seriously reason about performance and optimization options.

Comment: Maybe you don't even need to calculate root at all, you certainly sound more competent to highly likely knowing your stuff, and really needing the root, but I have seen several times in my life clueless people calculate square root just to compare the results with some distance constant or sort by it... *facepalm*

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is Microsoft Specific `naked` `fast call` of the standard `sqrt` function.

For detail info please check Microsoft documentation.

The naked storage-class attribute is a Microsoft-specific extension to the C language. For functions declared with the naked storage-class attribute, the compiler generates code without prolog and epilog code. You can use this feature to write your own prolog/epilog code sequences using inline assembler code. Naked functions are particularly useful in writing virtual device drivers.
See: [Naked functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21d5kd3a.aspx).

The `__fastcall` calling convention specifies that arguments to functions are to be passed in registers, when possible. This calling convention only applies to the x86 architecture. Take a look at:
[__fastcall](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xa169sk.aspx)

`__fastcall` was introduced a long time ago by Microsoft. Typically fastcall calling conventions pass one or more arguments in registers which reduces the number of memory accesses required for the call. With on-chip caching, the gain from passing things in registers is not a much gain as it use to be.
 And `__stdcall` may be actually faster now.